# (unset CDPATH) >/dev/null 2>&1 && unset CDPATH

Tags: shell

I read the following statement in a shell script:

```
(unset CDPATH) >/dev/null 2>&1 && unset CDPATH
```

Why there are two "unset CDPATH"? Can the last one be deleted?

Comment: What are you having problems with?  The shell notation?  The way CDPATH works? How it might get in the way?

Answer (score 3):

The first `(unset CDPATH) >/dev/null 2>&1` command tries to unset `CDPATH`, but does so in a sub-shell (that's the parentheses), with errors and output sent to `/dev/null`.  If that succeeds, then it unsets CDPATH in the main shell.  If it fails to unset CDPATH, then it does not try in the main shell.  This avoids error messages about not being able to unset CDPATH from interfering with the output of the configure script where it is used.

I'm not sure why or when such elaborate tests were necessary, but presumably on some machine, somewhere, at some time, the operation `unset CDPATH` was not allowed and messed around with the output of the configure scripts.  Note that the auto-configuration shell scripts are rather weird — anything but idiomatic shell — for all they are very portable in aggregate.  They attempt to deal with the weirdnesses of systems you've never heard of, likely some of which were obsolete before you <s>were born</s> graudated from primary school.  The reasons for many of the tests have probably been lost in the mists of time; there was once a system where the circumlocution was necessary, but it may well have been twenty years ago on a system that is no longer in active use.

Comment: Thank you,Jonathan Leffler. It's just what I need.

Comment: The autoconf manual in this case says what the broken systems were. In the https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.61/html_node/Limitations-of-Builtins.html#Limitations-of-Builtins "Limitations of Builtins" section it says:"In some nonconforming shells (e.g., Bash 2.05a), unset FOO fails when FOO is not set. Also, Bash 2.01 mishandles unset MAIL in some cases and dumps core."